# How to embed a wave file in html (cross platform)

Tags: html, linux, media

I want to embed a wave file (or mp3) in html. There is no problem for windows platforms. User can install a windows media player plugin. But WMP does not support linux. Is there any way to do that besides using Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look to a [Javascript implemtation](http://technicalninja.com/weblog/?p=5) (origanilly from [Digital Medias](http://digitalmedia.oreilly.com/2005/02/23/mp3_embed.html)).

[Here](http://www.technicalninja.com/projects/musicPlayer/) is a demo

But depending on what you want to do, it's generally not a good idea to provide music on website...

Comment: I am working a web-based diagnose tool, which is used to playback wave files (generated by some special devices).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "embed a wave file in html"? You want to play an external file of hold that file inline in the html?

I do belive that you want to play an external file, as holding that file inline would be an overkill.

So, to play an external file, why not use a flash player (http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac) or the new HTML5 element (http://ajaxian.com/archives/its-friday-play-some-drums-html5-style) ? I do belive flash is more lightweight than WMP and is cross-platform.

WMP might not exist on linux, but there are packages available for Firefox on linux that installs avi and mp3 handlers (at least mplayer does this, don't know about other players)

Comment: Thanks for showing this cool player. But this player seems not to support wave files. I am not sure, if I need a special license for converting and playing mp3 files for commercial propose.

Answer (score 1):

Really nice and easy example published by Google : 
http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/wave/embed/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_browsersounds.asp) will usually tell you all you need to know about html authoring